# How to bind post parameters to action parameters in controller?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

The action is like that:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Update(int id, string userName, string firstName, string lastName, string email, string role, string returnUrl = null)
{ 
    ...
}
```

When I debug the app the parameters are always null in the body of the method, even though they are not null in the request.

```
0%5Bid%5D=10&1%5BuserName%5D=Mike99&2%5BfirstName%5D=Mike&3%5BlastName%5D=Johnson&4%5Bemail%5D=mike.johnson%40live.com&5%5Brole%5D=user
```

[image: http post]

Routing configuration:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
};
```

Request is made by Ajax:

```
$.post("/Users/Update", postData)
    .done(function (data) {
        row.find(".changed").attr('class', 'editable');
        dataTable.draw();
    });
```

It seems that the action gets the correct data when I hit it with Postman, it just doesn't like data sent by jQuery.

So the question becomes: how to properly format data sent by AJAX?

Data sent by Postman:

```
id=10&userName=Mike99&firstName=Mike&lastName=Johnson&email=mike.johnson%40mail.com&role=user
```

Contrast it with data sent by AJAX:

```
0%5Bid%5D=10&1%5BuserName%5D=Mike99&2%5BfirstName%5D=Mike&3%5BlastName%5D=Johnson&4%5Bemail%5D=mike.johnson%40live.com&5%5Brole%5D=user
```

`postData` looks like this, when using `console.log(postData)`:

```
{0: {…}, 1: {…}, 2: {…}, 3: {…}, 4: {…}, 5: {…}}
0: {id: 10}
1: {userName: "Mike99"}
2: {firstName: "Mike"}
3: {lastName: "Johnson"}
4: {email: "mike.johnson@mail.com"}
5: {role: "user"}
```

Here's how `postData` is built:

```js
 var row = $(this).parents("tr");
                        var id = [{ id: dataTable.row(row).data().Id }];

                        divFields = row.find("div.editable").map(function () {
                            var value = this.className === "editable changed" ? this.innerText : null;
                            return {
                                [this.dataset.name]: value
                            }

                        }).get();

                        selectFields = row.find("select.editable").map(function () {
                            var value = this.className === "editable changed" ? $(this).find(":selected").text() : null;
                            return {
                                [this.dataset.name]: value
                            }

                        }).get();

                        var fields = id.concat(divFields.concat(selectFields));

                        var postData = Object.assign({}, fields);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you're building up a `fields` array that represents the form values, which ends up looking something like this:

```
[
    { id: 10 },
    { userName: "Mike99" },
    { firstName: "Mike" },
    { lastName: "Johnson" },
    { email: "mike.johnson@mail.com" },
    { role: "user" }
]
```

When you use `Object.assign({}, fields)`, you end up copying the properties of `fields` into a new object, but these properties are 0...5. This means you end up with an object that looks like this:

```
{
    0: { id: 10 },
    1: { userName: "Mike99" },
    2: { firstName: "Mike" },
    3: { lastName: "Johnson" },
    4: { email: "mike.johnson@mail.com" },
    5: { role: "user" }
}
```

When this gets serialised by jQuery into a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content-type, it ends up being something that cannot be parsed by the ASP.NET Core model-binder. You've already included what that looks like in the question, so I won't repeat it here.

One solution (of many possibilities), it to use the spread operator (`...`) on `fields`, like this:

```
Object.assign({}, ...fields)
```

This splits out `fields` into the individual objects that it contains and assigns them to to the resulting object.